# AJAX to update micropost vote up/down partial only refreshes the most recent post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial-views

Using Rails 3, JRuby.

I wanted to incorporate a "vote up" and "vote down" rating for my Rails social application, that allows users to essentially like and dislike posts. This worked great, however refreshed the whole page whenever a post was voted on. To solve this, I wanted to implement a partial refresh that would only update that particular post score, within the post feed.

I followed my usual pattern to implementing AJAX partial refreshing, however, the outcome isn't quite what I had in mind. Instead of refreshing the post I like/dislike, it refreshes the most recent post with the new score of the post I just liked/disliked.

I've identified this as a partial refreshing problem, because when I refresh the whole page manually, each post has its correct like/dislike score (including the one I intended to alter). I believe the problem is to do with the way my page renders posts to the page using a "do block". My problem is, I cannot figure out how to get the desired behaviour of correctly refreshing the micropost I voted on. Here is some of my code:

_micropost.html.erb (partial)

```
<% microposts.each do |mp| %>
<div class="profile_block gradient ">
    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="top-bar">
        <small class="badge sharp">Post</small>
        <!-- post/ article options -->
        <% if mp.user_id == current_user.id %>       
          <%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>'.html_safe, '#', class: "comment_link pull-right"%>
        <% end %>

        <%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>'.html_safe, increment_micropost_path(mp.id), class: "comment_link pull-right", :remote => true%>

        <%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>'.html_safe, decrement_micropost_path(mp.id), class: "comment_link pull-right", :remote => true %>

        <div id="global" class="pull-right badge"><%= render :partial => 'microposts/rating', :locals => {:micro => mp} %></div>
    </header> 
(....)
<% end %>
</div>
```

_home.html.erb

```
(....)
<div id="gf" class="left_col">          
    <%= render :partial => 'microposts/micropost', :locals => {:microposts => @microposts }, :remote => true %>
</div>
(....)
```

my _rating.html.erb partial (the bit that displays the information)

```
<%= micro.rating.to_i %>
```

controller (i'll just show the increment method, they're both near identical

```
#increments micropost rating by 1
def increment
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    @increment = lambda { |micropost| micropost.update_attribute(:rating, micropost.rating.to_i + 1) }
    @increment.call @micropost
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to root_url}
        format.js
    end
end
```

and the corresponding increment.js.html

```
$('#global').html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'microposts/rating', :locals => {:micro => @micropost} %>");
```

I mentioned above that the actual incrementing/ decrementing feature of the micropost works fine- it's just re-rendering this information using AJAX that's not behaving as intended. 
Any ideas, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you have multiple `div#global` in your code (because of the `each` loop), so the browser will only recognize the first one. Change `global` from an id to a class and then it should work. I would also add a `data-num` attribute to the `div` and assign it the `id` of the database object (not to be confused with the HTML `id`). Something like this:

```
<div class="pull-right badge global" data-num="<%= mp.id %>"><%= render :partial => 'microposts/rating', :locals => {:micro => mp} %></div>
```

Then, in your `increment.js.erb` (I think you meant that instead of `.js.html`...), change it to:

```
$('div.global[data-num="<%= @micropost.id %>"]').html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'microposts/rating', :locals => {:micro => @micropost} %>");
```

That way, the JavaScript will always know which one to update because it's based on the database ID.

Comment: It works! - Never knew you could assign a div a data-number that corresponds to the id of the object, makes sense when multiple divs are dynamically generated. Hope others find this as useful as I did.

Comment: Yep. Any attribute, on any element, prefixed with `data-`, will be ignored by the browser itself and is generally used by JavaScript. For instance, if you want a confirmation box when you click on a specific link, you just add `data-confirm="Are you sure?"` to the link, and JavaScript will automatically show the box.